# Laravel yield is not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes, sections

this is my route

```
Route::get('/', 'SpielplanController@getSpielplan');
```

this is my app layout page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dateneingabe</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <script src="{{asset('/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    @yield('contentSpiel')
    @yield('A')
</body>
</html>
```

Now here is my @yield('contentSpiel')

```
@extends('app')

@section('contentSpiel')

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Spiele</label>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" name="spiele" id="spiele">

                @foreach($alleSpiele as $alleSpieleOutput)     
                    <option value="{!! $alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft !!}">{{$alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft}}</option>     
                @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

<script>
    $('#spiele').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);

        var spielID = e.target.value;

        //ajax
        $.get('/spieler-table?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){

            //success data
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

and here is my section A

```
@extends('app')

@section('A')

<h2>asd</h2>

@endsection
```

I can not understand why I get only the section @yield('contentSpiel') back in my browser. What I have to change that both @yields are in my browser?

Comment: Why are you extending app twice? Are you combining two views in a controller or something?

Answer (score 0):

you can load only one view from your controller. now if you have one view but you want to yield multiple portions of it then u can try this example :

```
 @extends('layouts.app')


    @section('contentSpiel')
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Spiele</label>
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="spiele" id="spiele">
 @foreach($alleSpiele as $alleSpieleOutput) <option value="{!! $alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft !!}">$alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft}}</option>         
    @endforeach
</select>
    </div>

    <script>
    $('#spiele').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);

    var spielID = e.target.value;

    //ajax
    $.get('/spieler-table?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){

    //success data
    console.log(data);
    });
    });
    </script>
    @endsection

    @section('A')
    <h2>asd</h2>
    @endsection
```

now if you will print your value in one view and want to load another view like sider bar in your master then just include it.

this is my app layout page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dateneingabe</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <script src="{{asset('/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    @yield('contentSpiel')
    @include('your_view_file_path')
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in **layout**:

```
<body>
    @yield('contentSpiel')
    @yield('A')
</body>

@stack('scripts')
```

***contecontentSpiel.blade.php*** view *(this view should be returned in action)*

```
@extends('app')

@section('contentSpiel')

    <div class="form-group">
        ...
    </div>

@endsection

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $('#spiele').on('change', function(e){
            ...
        });
    </script>
@endpush

@section('A')
   ...
@endsection
```

if you want to have several blade files... you can create ***sectionAForContentSpiel.blade.php*** and move here section A code

```
@section('A')
   ...
@endsection
```

and then in ***contecontentSpiel.blade.php***

```
@include('sectionAForContentSpiel')
```

PS:
using `@stack('scripts')` and `@push('scripts') - @endpush` you can include scripts in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your app layout page like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dateneingabe</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <script src="{{asset('/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <section class="contentSpiel">

    @yield('contentSpiel')

  </section>


  <section class="A">

    @yield('A')

  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help for you !!!